# Should we install react and react-dom in --save or --save-dev mode?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, react-dom

Some tutorials use --save mode while some use --save-dev mode.

Both of them use Babel, saying that it is used to convert React into plain Javascript that browsers understand. That means the final bundle will have Javascript. In that case why do we need to install react and react-dom in --save mode? --save-dev mode should suffice right?

Also, statements like import React from 'react', do they go into prod build bundle files? If not, how are statements like React.createClass work without React being available in that corresponding scope/memory-space?

Answer (score 8):

`--save` mode is for packages that your app will use when it's running, like React. `--save-dev` are for packages that help you develop like linters, module bundlers, transpilers (eg Babel).

This separation is almost entirely for your benefit -- putting everything into your main dependencies with `--save` won't break anything, but it's considered bad organization.

By the way, NPM 5 and above will automatically save packages, so the `--save` flag isn't necessary anymore. (You still need to use `--save-dev` to mark packages as a "development dependency").

> Also, statements like import React from 'react', do they go into prod build bundle files? If not, how are statements like React.createClass work without React being available in that corresponding scope/memory-space?

Yes, that `import React from 'react'` ends up in the bundle, but using a regular JavaScript function instead of an import statement. You can open up the bundle file in your text editor to see what your code has been transformed into.